# How to rotate glyphs in Bokeh?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am trying to generate oriented triangles like so:

```
fig.triangle(x, y, angle=theta)
```

But the glyphs always show up un-rotated, regardless of theta. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

***[As of Bokeh 0.8.1]*** Not all glyphs support rotation. Sometimes it simply makes no sense, e.g. for a `line` what point would you rotate around? An `angle` property was not added to "markers" in general, either, because many are rotationally symmetric. But, perhaps adding an `angle` property specifically to the triangles is reasonable. I encourage you to submit a feature request issue on the Bokeh GH issue tracker: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get `angle` working for any glyphs. Do you know of any that support it?

Comment: `square` and `rect` both do. `ray` also takes an `angle`. Others, like `wedge` and `annular_wedge` have `start_angle` and `end_angle`. It doesn't make sense for lots of others. `circle` and other markers are symmetric. `quad` is by definition axis-aligned. Things like `patch` and `line` don't have any obvious "point to rotate about" It would be more helpful if you explain what you'd actually like to accomplish with your data.

Comment: Okay, I can get it working for `rect` and `ray`, but not `square`. I'm just trying to add arrowheads along a line.

Comment: If it is not working for `square` then that is a bug, please file an issue at the Bokeh GH issue tracker: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: In the mean time you should be able to use `rect` in place of `square` as a workaround.